# Unicode and :alpha:

Tags: regex, elixir

Why is this `false`:

```
iex(1)> String.match?("汉语漢語", ~r/^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
false
```

But this is `true`?:

```
iex(2)> String.match?("汉语漢語", ~r/[[:alpha:]]/)
true
```

Sometimes `[:alpha:]` is unicode and sometimes it's not?

## EDIT:

I don't think my original example was clear enough.

Why is this `false`:

```
iex(1)> String.match?("汉", ~r/^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
false
```

But this is `true`?:

```
iex(2)> String.match?("汉", ~r/[[:alpha:]]/)
true
```

Comment: Try with the `/u` modifier: `~r/^[[:alpha:]]+$/u`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the `u` modifier.  I could also have done `\p{L}`.  My question is why does `[:alpha:]` work differently in these two examples?

Comment: When you pass the string to the regex in a non-Unicode mode, it is treated as an array of bytes, not as a Unicode string. See `IO.puts byte_size("汉语漢語")` and `IO.puts String.length("汉语漢語")` difference. There are bytes in the string that cannot be matched with the `[:alpha:]` POSIX character class. Thus, the first expression does not work, while the second will as it only needs 1 character to return a valid match.

Comment: @stribizhev you should post your comment as an answer so others can find it more easily.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: Sorry, I was busy with kids. Added now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you pass the string to the regex in a non-Unicode mode, it is treated as an array of bytes, not as a Unicode string. See `IO.puts byte_size("汉语漢語")` (12, all bytes that the input consists of: `230,177,137,232,175,173,230,188,162,232,170,158`) and `IO.puts String.length("汉语漢語")` (4, the Unicode "letters") difference. There are bytes in the string that cannot be matched with the `[:alpha:]` POSIX character class. Thus, the first expression does not work, while the second works as it only needs 1 character to return a valid match.

To properly match Unicode strings with PCRE regex library (that is used in Elixir), you need to enable the Unicode mode with `/u` modifier:

```
IO.puts String.match?("汉语漢語", ~r/^[[:alpha:]]+$/u)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/9Nyte7) (prints `true`)

See [Elixir regex reference](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Regex.html):

> `unicode (u)` - enables unicode specific patterns like `\p` and changes modifiers like `\w`, `\W`, `\s` and friends to also match on unicode. It expects valid unicode strings to be given on match.